# SVN - programmatically commit file - Error svn: E200009: xyz.java is not under version control

Tags: java, svn, commit

What I want to achive is , creating two seperate system with two seperate SVN. But one the application will be "Master-Application" for some infra-structure  component codes. So when I develop some code for these components I want to ftp these code to client application and this client application will commit these codes programmatically to its own SVN. Deployment of these codes will be a matter of Managers of this second client application.

So I write a small code for this auto commit of these java source code files.It opens ZIP file, reads files of project and commit each files. When I do this , SVN throws this exception

svn: E200009: 'D:\cmsNodeFolder\01102015-162224\CMS SMG Test Project\src\cb\smg\test\deneme\Deneme.java' is not under version control

But I am sure that this project and file are exist on my second SVN.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You need to `svn add` before you can commit.